# Ajax GET request with data variables

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to do a GET request with ajax to a Laravel function. This request has the following parameters: $id, $date, $service_time. In the Laravel function I want to convert the date to a Carbon date. Is there a solution to convert the right java-script date format to this Carbon format? I only need the date not the time. When I use below code I get a Unix time-stamp and when I select 05-10-2017 I get the result 04-10-2017.

```
var date = document.getElementById("startdate").value;
var newDate = new Date(date);
newDate.format("mm/dd/yy");
```

One other question I send the parameters through a URL in ajax. Is there a better way to do this?

```
var base_url = "{{ url('/') }}";
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url : base_url+"/company/available/1/18-10-2017/30",
            //data: {id : 1, date: "2017/10/18", service_time: service_time},
            success : function(data){
                $.each($(data), function(key, value) {
                    if(value.availity == 1) {
                        console.log(value.availity);
                      $('#available').append($("<div class='beschikbaar-style'></div>").text(value.time));
                    }
              });
            }
        });
    });
```

This is the route that calls the function:

```
Route::get('company/available/{id}/{date}/{service_time}', 'AppointmentsController@get_available_times')->name('companies.getAvailableTimes');
```

This is the function that is called:

```
function get_available_times($company_id, $date, $service_time = false)
{
     // $company_id = 1; 
    //$date = "2017-10-18";
    // $service_time = 30;

     $day = new Carbon($date);
```

Comment: Instead of sending them as part of the URL, you can use a POST request. Also, there's no `format()` function for `Date` objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same problem with sending javascript date to Laravel and it is because of timezone part of Date object.

Maybe this function can help to convert Date to SQL formated string. It's not best javascript but will help :)

```
function sqlDate (date) {
  var y = date.getFullYear();
  var m = date.getMonth() + 1;
  var d = date.getDate();
  var s = y.toString() + '-';
  if (m < 10) {
    s += '0' + m.toString() + '-';
  } else {
    s += m.toString() + '-';
  }
  if (d < 10) {
    s += '0' + d.toString();
  } else {
    s += d.toString();
  }
  return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     $date = "2017-10-18";
     $newDate = Carbon::parse($date)->now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
     dd($newDate); // 2017-10-05 15:52:17
```

Answer (score 0):

You can to use the createFromFormat function, like this:

```
$day = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('mm-dd-yy', $date);
```